# WP_Query returning unlimited number of posts, showposts and posts_per_page not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hack a WordPress Theme that uses WP_Query for a "Recent Posts" widget. Currently it is limited to return only a specific Category, while I'd like it to return a limited number of posts from all categories. I have tried and succeeded at this before with other Plugins/Themes. In this case it doesn't work, irrespective of what change I try to implement, I get 4000+ posts in the query.

```
         <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('cat='.$category.'&showposts='.$postnum);
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
```

What could be the common culprit of not having showposts or post_per_page working correctly as a limiter?

Comment: `showposts` has been replaced...You may want to try using `posts_per_page`.

Comment: Yep I tried both, sorry if my phrasing was unclear. same result with either one.

Answer (score 1):

are you able to get a correct output from your variable $postnum ?

also try using this

`$args = array('category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => 3);`

`<?php
    query_posts( $args );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo 'content';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>`

Comment: yep, $postnum works fine. The problem manifests itself as soon as I remove the cat=$category part, effectively breaking the post limit. As long as I have the category argument in there, it works.